# ifft with Heaviside

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have asked a similar question already but sadly I was not able to solve my problem.
I am looking for the inverse of a Fourier transformation on a heaviside function

Wolframalpha already gave me the exact solution of the FT but the calculated ifft does not compute to the same heaviside.

my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=1000
x=np.linspace(-10,10,N)
dx=np.abs(x[0]-x[1])
freq=np.fft.fftfreq(N,dx)

#solution:
H=-np.heaviside(5-np.abs(x),1)

#the FT of the heviside according to wolframaplha
s_x=-np.sqrt(2/np.pi)*np.sin(5*x)/x

#the ifft:
s_k=np.fft.ifft(s_x)

plt.plot(freq,(s_k),label='calc')
plt.plot(x,H,label='exact')
plt.legend()
```

As one can see the Solution has a simular form of a box, but does not start at x=5 nor has the right amplitude.
Additionally is the amplitude in both the negative and positive area.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the Heaviside function with the box function. The box function's FT can be trivially computed analytically and delivers the Sinc-function.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the inverse FT which should be the box function. Here the heaviside is a way of creating the box function